# Нужна помощь, как вывести количество зарегестрированых пользователей на HTML страницу сайта

Tags: php, html

Нужна помощь, как вывести количество зарегестрированых пользователей из БД на HTML страницу сайта, Пример ( Пользователей сайта 45)

Comment: Запросить число пользователей у базы данных и внедрить полученный результат в html-код страницы

Comment: мне всегда так нравятся такие вопросы ))) приведите код, как вы пробовали их вывести, если вообще пробовали. Вопросы такого рода не задаются тут, гугл в помощь "Как посчитать количество записей в mysql php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если проблема в запросе к базе, то вот простой sql запрос, который выведет количество найденных строк:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `user_count` FROM `user`
```

В конце если есть условие добавляем в запрос (к примеру):

```
WHERE `user`.`type` = 1
```

Если же вы вообще ничего не понимаете и не знаете как и что устроено, то почитайте лучше сперва функции php и начните с простого, как вывести данные из БД с помощью php.